# Remove tests classifier of Maven jar:test-jar goal?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I have configured the `maven-jar-plugin` as follow:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}.main</finalName>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}.tests</finalName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I want my output JAR files to be called `ARTIFACT.main.jar` and `ARTIFACT.tests.jar`. The former is working, but the later comes out as `ARTIFACT.tests-tests.jar` instead. Is there any way to adjust the above configuration to remove the `-tests` classifier?

Comment: The finalName is only working for the target folder and will not working if you deploy artifacts to a repository. Apart from that this is a naming schema.

Comment: An other question is: Why do you like to name them different? Special purpose for this?

Comment: @khmarbaise to be honest I just didn't like the look of it. I realise that deviating from conventions simply due to aesthetic preference is not a good idea, but this is just for my own learning, not use in anger

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i just wanted to know if you might have other reasons to go that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, after looking at the `maven-jar-plugin` source code, I don't think it is possible to remove the `tests` classifier from the test jar.

The [`execute`](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-jar-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/jar/AbstractJarMojo.java#L253) method that is called during the goal `test-jar` takes the output of the method `getClassifier()` to append a classifier:

```
File jarFile = createArchive();
String classifier = getClassifier();
if ( classifier != null )
{
    projectHelper.attachArtifact( getProject(), getType(), classifier, jarFile );
}
else
{
    getProject().getArtifact().setFile( jarFile );
}
```

and the [`getClassifier()`](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-jar-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/jar/TestJarMojo.java#L54-L57) method returns the hard-coded String "tests" for the `test-jar` goal.

I found an "Improvement" ([MJAR-199](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-199)) in the maven-jar-plugin JIRA about this. Feel free to vote for it!

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but I agree with your analysis